What is the best way to cut a cinder block wall filled with concrete?
I have a CMU wall with filled concrete (and possibly rebar). It is 6 inches wide, and I need to remove a depth of about 6 inches along a distance of about 16 ft to make a rough opening for a large sliding door. What is the best way to achieve this and with what tools? I am doing this as a DIY project.
I was considering renting an electric concrete saw and cutting through. But I'm not sure if depending on the diameter, if I might need to cut from both sides? The other thing is I'm not sure if it will be difficult to create a consistently level cut with such a heavy tool, over a long distance. Of course, I have no experience with this particular tool, so that's just a guess. Thanks in advance!
Added Sketchup drawing


Pictures? Drawings? That is a large opening. What are your plans to support what is above the opening?

Unless this is just a foundation/wall with nothing on top/being supported by it, your bigger problem is going to be supporting the weight above it.   16 feet is getting into wanting a support beam with posts.

Structural issues aside, you can drill holes in the concrete and mount a length of reasonably straight lumber to the wall to use as a guide (and help hold up the saw).

Unless this is approver by an engineer, this sounds like a bad idea.  Blocks are not filled with concrete and rebar if it is not needed to add support.

Talked to a structural engineer and there will be a steel flitch beam supporting the opening. Will have to build a temporary wall to take care of that first, indeed.
